# PHP: increment a number by 5 each time

Tags: php, math

I'm trying to reproduce the following as a one-liner.

```
if($l < 10) $next = 5; return;
if($l < 20) $next = 10; return;
if($l < 30) $next = 15; return;
if($l < 40) $next = 20; return;
if($l < 50) $next = 25; return;
if($l < 60) $next = 30; return;
if($l < 70) $next = 35; return;
if($l < 80) $next = 40; return;
if($l < 90) $next = 45; return;
if($l < 100) $next = 50; return;
```

(not syntactically correct but you get the idea)

So that if the number is less than 10, $next is 5, and if the number is less than 20 then it's 10.

`$next = ((round($l, -1)-5));` is as close as I can get to it but that gives

```
5
15
25
35
45
55
65
75
85
```

not the desired 5, 10, 15, 20 .. etc

What is the correct way to write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add 10 to your number, then divide the result by 10 and round it down to the nearest (floor) integer, you will then have the number by which to multiply 5, which will yield your result... so...
let's say your number is 47.

47 + 10 = 57

57 / 10 = 5.7

floor 5.7 = 5

5x5 = 25

```
return floor(($i + 10)/10) * 5
```

Comment: One of the parenthesis isn't closed properly

Comment: sorry about that (fixed it)... but my answer is "righter" than the answer you selected because if you don't floor the result you'll get a number that isn't rounded, in my example you'd get 5.7 * 5 = 28.5.

Answer (score 1):

`(($l + 10) / 10) * 5` will do the trick

Comment: you need to floor your initial equation, before multiplying by 5, else the result will be wrong... look at my answer for details :)

Answer (score 0):

DIVDIDE through ten (and round that to int), then multiply that with 5 ... 100/10=10 => 10*5=50

Answer (score 0):

This might do:

```
$i=10;
while($l < $i){
    $next = $i / 2;
    $i+=10;
}
```

Comment: You know using semicolons is cheating. Otherwise, all code can be made into one-liners...

Comment: you are right. after i've wrote that code, i saw the "single line" part

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it's not harder than;

```
$next = floor($l/10)*5+5;
```